# setBackground to buttons in a table

Tags: android, user-interface, android-tablelayout, tablerow, viewflipper

I have a series of buttons, in tables, in a ViewFlipper, so I can paginate the tables. If I set them no background, they keep their margins between each other. But I need to "make them pretty", so I added a gradient to the buttons. But now they are not keeping their margins any longer.

I am adding them programatically, looping an ArrayList of the texts the button have to have, adding them in the proper row of the table, and so on. Like this:

```
final Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText(array.get(i));
btn.setTextSize(10);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.i("TAG", "Botón pulsado: " + texto);
        goToModule(texto);
    }
});
btn.setHeight(height);
btn.setWidth(width);
btn.setOnTouchListener(parentListener);
btn.post(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,getDrawableForText(texto),null, null);
        btn.setPadding(0,35,0,0);
        int[] colors = {Color.parseColor("#008000"),Color.parseColor("#ADFF2F")};
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR, colors);
        gd.setCornerRadius(30f);
        btn.setBackground(gd);
    }
});
row1.addView(btn);
```

The result in the screen is like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to make the buttons look like the ones without the gradient, I mean, respecting the margins between each other, to make them look more like a proper table?

Thank you.

Comment: Try applying the `margin` the same way you have applied the `padding`.

Comment: This is default behavior of the button when it has no background it has little margins, but when you set background color or drawable the margin removed and you need to add margins by yourself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding margin to button

```
 TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Added, now I see the margins, but a bit of the buttons at the right and the bottom gets out of the screen and are not seen...

Comment: Ok, changing height and width of the buttons to height -20 and width -20 did the trick. Thank you for your help, Im marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

try change margin to padding in xml.